# Convert any date of the month to first day of the month

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

How do I convert any date of the month to first day of the month?

E.g. "2017-12-08", "2015-09-28" to "2017-12-01" and "2015-09-01"?

The only way I thought is to convert to character and `gsub` the last two digits into "01"

Comment: I think it is a bit tough to consider this a dupe since if the op wanted say `05`, then some of the answers in the other would not work.

Comment: @headpoint but OP didn't want `05`, they wanted `01`, besides there are other answers in the link which would not require a lot of effort to change from `01` to `05`.

Comment: @RonakShah yes, I said "if the op wanted" and implied some answers would work, too. You haven't added anything new to what I said. People are expected to give examples of their problems.

Comment: @headpoint so then why `I think it is a bit tough to consider this a dupe` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Some answers in the link does not work for this questions. Same way. there can be answers to this questions that would not necessarily be an answer to the linked questions. I, unfortunately, do not know one. I think it is fair to call this a dupe if you say there any good answer to this question that would also be an answer to the linked question.